# Sequelize sort by associated model's field

Tags: sequelize.js

I have Chat, User and Message models, Message belongs to User and Chats can have multiple Users and User can have multiple Chats. I have working Sequelize method `chat.getUsers()` that returns unsorted users, and I want users sorted by `createdAt` of their last message in that Chat.

What I have so far is this:

```
     UserModel.findAll({
        include: [
          {
            model: ChatModel,
            where: { id: chat.id },
            include: [
              {
                model: MessageModel,
              },
            ],
            order: [[MessageModel, 'createdAt', 'DESC']],
          },
        ],
      });
```

`where` part filters users correctly but the `order` part does nothing.

Here is the complete database structure:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
    [Task, 'createdAt', 'DESC'],
```

Source: http://sequelize.org/master/manual/querying.html

Comment: according to the source